# What function is more efficient?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and i wanted to know if there is a difference between these 2 functions:

```
public static String function1(int x) {
    String res = "";
    if(x > 10)
        res = "a";
    else
        res = "b";

    return res;
}
```

and:

```
public static String function2(int x) {
    if(x > 10)
        return "a";

    return "b";
}
```

and I'm not speaking on the length of the code, only efficiency.

Comment: In _theory_, version 2 is more efficient, but in practise it should be negligible.

Comment: @Alnitak Why version 2?

Comment: I think the second one is more efficient since it avoid to allocate memory for a variable, affect it and then read it. But maybe the compiler is able to detect that res is useless and compile the same for both solution

Comment: what about static String function2(int x) { return x > 10 ? "a" : "b";}

Comment: function2 is more efficient, check on one condition and have no variables. but the code is simple compiler can't notice the difference.

Comment: Why don't you write a microbenchmark and test it yourself?

Comment: @ZeyadEtman Version 1 also checks just one condition.

Comment: I mean 'else' doesn't exist.

Comment: An `else` is not a "condition", it's just the code that's executed when the `if` branch isn't taken.

Comment: One could argue this is a duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103)

Answer (score 6):

The second version is in theory more efficient, decompiling to:

```
public static java.lang.String function1(int);
Code:
   0: ldc           #2                  // String
   2: astore_1
   3: iload_0
   4: bipush        10
   6: if_icmple     12
   9: ldc           #3                  // String a
  11: areturn
  12: ldc           #4                  // String b
  14: areturn
```

whereas the version with the assignment decompiles to:

```
public static java.lang.String function1(int);
Code:
   0: ldc           #2                  // String
   2: astore_1
   3: iload_0
   4: bipush        10
   6: if_icmple     15
   9: ldc           #3                  // String a
  11: astore_1
  12: goto          18
  15: ldc           #4                  // String b
  17: astore_1
  18: aload_1
  19: areturn
```

where it can be seen that the additional variable is created and returned.

However **in practise the difference in actual runtime performance should be negligible**.   The JIT compiler would (hopefully) optimise away the useless variable, and in any case unless the code was in a hot code path according to your profiler then this would certainly count as premature optimisation.

Comment: I was just writing this exact answer. For the benefit of the OP, the bytecode was obtained by compiling a class containing these methods using `javac ClassName.java` then running `javap -c ClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions end up creating a string either `"a"` or `"b"` and return it out.
But version 2 is better in term of efficiency, which doesn't create an redundant empty string `""` in memory.

Comment: `""` is interned (as a string literal), so no redundant empty string will be actually created.

Comment: @lexicore The code will add the empty string to the intern pool, so it *is* created by the code.